# Is my proof that $\mathscr P(A)\subseteq \mathscr P(B) \Leftrightarrow A\subseteq B$ correct?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, solution-verification, first-order-logic

Translating the power set and subset symbols for their corresponding logical symbols:

$\begin{align}\mathscr P(A)\subseteq \mathscr P(B) &\Leftrightarrow \forall y(y\subseteq A \rightarrow y\subseteq B)\tag 1 \\&\Leftrightarrow \forall y \forall x ((x \in y \rightarrow x \in A)\rightarrow (x \in y \rightarrow x \in B)\tag 2 \\ &\Leftrightarrow \forall y \forall x ((x \in y \lor x \notin A)\lor x \notin y \lor x \in B) \tag 3 \\&\Leftrightarrow \forall y \forall x (x \notin A \lor x \notin y \lor x \in B)\tag 4 \end{align}$

And since it can't be true that for all $y,$ $x\notin y$, then we can write the above expression as:

$\Leftrightarrow \forall x (x \in A \rightarrow  x \in B) \Leftrightarrow A\subseteq B $

My problem with the proof is this final step, because I am not sure what the universe of these variables is. I believe this statement is always correct, but it seems that we must assume $\forall y \forall x (x \notin y)$ is always false. How does one go about proving this, or how can one prove what I set out to prove?

P.S. Using the info the comments have given me, there are some problems with my reasoning in lines two and beyond. I try to correct it here:

$\begin{align} \forall y(y\subseteq A \rightarrow y\subseteq B) &\Leftrightarrow \forall y (\forall x(x \in y \rightarrow x \in A)\rightarrow \forall z(z \in y \rightarrow z \in B)) \\&\Leftrightarrow \forall y (\exists x (x \in y \land x \notin A)\lor \forall z(z \notin y \lor z \in B)) \end{align}$

And now I'm stuck.

Comment: Why not simply use that $A\in\mathcal P(A)\to A\in\mathcal P(B)$?

Comment: @Bernard Yes,thx, that's the way to go...Way simpler and to the point. I didn't think of that. Even so, I guess it's usefull to find out if that final step is correct.

Comment: Line 2 should be $\forall y~(\forall x~(x\in y\to y\in A)\to\forall z~(z\in y\to z\in B))$

Comment: Another problem is that  $x\in y\to y\in A$ is not $x\in y\vee c\notin A$, but $x\notin y\vee x\in A$, and similarly with $B$.

Comment: @bof I edited it to say "correct" , but it was edited out...